# Witcher 3 import save game

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-2

I decided to play the whole trilogy, importing saves along the way. It went fine until I finished 2nd (The Assassins of Kings) game and decided to import it into the 3rd game (Wild Hunt). Now the last save and auto save are both before I encountered Letho in Epilogue. And the game finished after these saves without giving me a chance to save my decision of leaving Letho alive.

Is there a way to fix it and transfer my choice to Wild Hunt?

Comment: I don't remember, whether the game actually saved again after the final encounter or not, but I can tell you Letho was alive in my playthrough and I just imported the latest save file.

Comment: By the time stamp, last auto save available to import was about 20 minutes before I finished conversation with Letho and finisehed the game. I guess I will use that one.

Answer (score 3):

In Wild Hunt you will have an interview with Nilfgaardian general Moorvran Voorhis during the early story mission Imperial Audience. during that conversation you have to answer few questions about events from "Witcher 2" that can affect the "Wild Hunt" storyline - one of those questions is the fate of Leto.

If you'll say that you've spared him, you will be able to meet him and after doing short quest, ask for his help.

[More info](http://au.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Importing_Save_Files)

Comment: I think that's only relevant, when you do not import a save. I can't remember Vorhees ever mentioning Letho.

Comment: Yup, I just passed that part few hours back, He never asked me anything about events from Witcher 2.